# How to add whitespaces in React JSX

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have this `li` tag

```
<li className='u-cursor--pointer u-padding-vertical-small c-start-retro-line'
  key={project.get('id')}
  onClick={() => this.handleProjectSelection(project.get('id'))} >
  <i className='fa fa-square' style={{color: project.get('color')}}></i>
  {project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No Project' : project.get('name')}
</li>
```

And I need to add an space between the `<i></i>` tag and what's inside the `{}` `{project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No Project' : project.get('name')}`

How can I do this? I tried `<span></span>` but It doesn't work (I need an extra space, not a new line)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try:

1) Either `{' '}` or `{" "}`:

```
<li>
    <i className="..."></i>
    {' '}my text
</li>
```

2) Simply use the HTML entity `&nbsp;`:

```
<li>
    <i className="..."></i>
    &nbsp;my text
</li>
```

3) Alternatively, you could insert spaces in the strings:

```
<li>
    <i className="..."></i>
    {project.get('name') === 'default' ? ' No Project' : ` ${project.get('name')}`}
</li>
```

In the last example, notice the use of [string substitution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use &nbsp in dangerouslySetInnerHTML when printing html content

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'sample html text: &nbsp;'}} />
```